# 'nodemon' não é reconhecido

Tags: node.js, nodemon

Após instalação do nodemon recebo o seguinte erro :

> 'nodemon' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
>   ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

Os seguintes comando foram passados:

- npm install -g nodemon
- npm install --save-dev nodemon

Comment: Reiniciou a sessão do terminal após a instalação?

Comment: sim, foi reiniciada

Comment: E tem certeza que a instalação ocorreu sem erros?

Comment: sim, sem nenhum erro , este foi o motivo de ter perguntado

Comment: Esse link abaixo vcs irão conseguir... linha de comando para instalar
sudo npm install nodemon -g
depois para rodar
sudo nodemon junto com endereço do arquivo .js https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4N0d8HhU5DE

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
npm install -g nodemon

npm install --save-dev nodemon

npm config get prefix

set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\"Aqui seu usuario"\AppData\Roaming\npm;
```

Achei esta solução este site https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-nao-consigo-instalar-o-nodemon-23149 assim e possivel utilizar o comando:

- nodemon server

Answer (score 5):

Primeiro passo será necessário obter  o caminho do prefixo da instalação do npm que pode ser resolvido digitando o seguinte comando:

`npm config get prefix`

O resultado será o caminho, copie-o e cole no próximo comando:

`set PATH=%PATH%;caminho;`

Exemplo

[image: comando-1.png]

Caso a configuração não persista então terá que configurar manualmente variável  de ambiente:

Indo em painel de controle, Sistema, Configurações avançadas de Sistema indo no botão Variáveis de Ambiente:

Primeiro passo em variáveis para meu usuário em Path clique no botão Editar e depois no botão Novo e adicionei o caminho obtido do promot de comando 
`npm config get prefix`

`C:\Users\lcsan\AppData\Roaming\npm`

E em seguida Ok e na variavel de sistema em PATH clique no botão Editar adicione o caminho de instalção do NodeJS

`C:\Program Files\nodejs`

feito isso reiniciar o computador

Answer (score 2):

O comando que você deve executar para o nodemon reconhecer seu server é:

```
nodemon SeuArquivoDeServidor.js
```

Você consegue ver nesse tutorial [aqui](https://scotch.io/courses/build-a-nodejs-website/using-express-and-nodemon).

Se quiser também pode especificar no seu arquivo package.json

Vai ficar algo parecido com:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon SeuArquivoDeServidor.js"
}
```

Então só vai ser preciso executar o comando no terminal

```
npm start
```

você consegue ler mais sobre na pagina do nodemon package [aqui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) e na própria documentação do nodemon [aqui](https://nodemon.io/).

Espero que isso tenha te ajudado.

Answer (score 2):

**Win 10 Solução**

1º Passo: Meu Computador / Propriedades / Configurações avançadas do sistema

2º Passo: Variáveis de Ambiente

3º Passo: Clique em cima da variável de ambiente PATH e depois clique em editar

4º Passo: Clique em novo e cole a seguinte linha
C:\Users\"Seu usuário"\AppData\Roaming\npm

5º Passo: Clique em OK e seja feliz :D

**Ah, não esqueça de reiniciar o prompt/editor !!!**

Answer (score 1):

Quando você vai executar algum comando de uma biblioteca do node, você não executa a biblioteca diretamente, e sim pelo node, pelo comando:

```
npm run <comando no package.json>
```

Nesse caso, com o nodemon você usuaria o comando abaixo:

```
npm run nodemon
```

Embora, se estiver configurado no package.json, você pode usar o nome definido lá. No meu caso, eu tenho um comando definido no meu package.json assim:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "ng serve"
}
```

Eu poderia usar ele direto como `npm ng serve` ou usar `npm run start`.

Comment: Mas instalado globalmente, alguns pacotes possuem CLI própria, vide Grunt e Gulp.

Comment: entendi, mais e o comando do nodemon mesmo, nao tem como setar o comando para utilizar por exemplo 'nodemon serve'

Answer (score 1):

Consegui utilizando os comandos abaixo pelo Power Shell [administrador]:

```
npm install -g npm
npm cache clean --force
npm update
npm install
```

Logo após iniciei o `nodemon ./bin/server.js` (no meu caso)

Answer (score 1):

Usar os seguintes passos:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

o npm devolve o local de instalação:

```
C:\Users\{seu usuario}\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon ->  C:\Users\{seu usuario}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js

> nodemon@2.0.7 postinstall C:\Users\leona\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0
```

Adicionar o primeiro endereço à variável de ambiente PATH. usando o poweshell seria assim:

```
$Env:path = $Env:path+"C:\Users\{seu usuário}\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon"
```

Answer (score -1):

Vá em Painel de Controle > Desinstalar um programa > procure pelo Node.js, no meu caso Windows 7 SO X86, tem um botão Reparar, quando reparei o Node o nodemon voltou a funcionar

Answer (score -1):

Precisei excluir a pasta .bin detro de node modules.

Reinstalei o nodemon via terminal npm instal nodemon -d.

para rodar a primeira vez foi nexessário executar npx nodemon index.js

Answer (score -3):

Abra o *PowerShell* como administrador e depois execute:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```